# What counts as a target for the purposes of targeted strikes?

Tags: helldivers-2

A couple of the air/orbital strikes (the Orbital Railcannon Strike and the Eagle 110mm Rocket Pods in particular) specify that they get fired at the largest target in close proximity to the beacon. But what counts as a target for these purposes? Is it just automatons and terminids? Or do enemy buildings count as targets?

[image: Offensive Strategem Permit - Orbital Railcannon Strike: A high-velocity railcannon round fired at the largest target in close proximity to the beacon. Targeting is automatic.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Railcannon and 110 Rocket targets the valid target with most health. All enemy units count as valid targets, and the attack will target the one with largest health pool.

Enemy buildings (Fabricators and Bug Holes) are targeted if there is no enemy with higher health pool around them.

Comment: Do rogue research stations (or anything that can be destroyed with a Hellbomb) also count as an enemy building?

Comment: Yes. If there are no other more valid targets, the attack will target them.